# Are Shiny and Dawn Stone present in PokéPelago?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm looking for evolutionary stones, so my Pokémon are doing "Path for Brilliant-Stone Hunting!" everyday. But after several days, I've never found any *Shiny Stones* or *Dawn Stones*, despite [Serebii listing them](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokepelago.shtml).

I know one of each can be found in [specific locations](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolutionary_stone), but I need more than one.
So I'm wondering if these stones can actually be obtained in PokéPelago. Or are these stones Sun-exclusive, like in [Malie City flea market](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Malie_City#Malie_City_proper_2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should chalk it up to poor RNG. From multiple sites, I've found no indication that Dawn Stones *or* Shiny Stones are version exclusive.

[This site](https://pokemongohub.net/poke-pelago-guide/) has them both down as rewards for the *Brilliant Stone Hunting!* path you mentioned.

[This site](https://daily.pokecommunity.com/2016/11/26/pokemon-sun-moon-item-locations/) also states that both the Dawn Stone and Shiny Stone can be acquired through PokéPelago.

Lastly, the availability of these stones is not listed under Serebii's [version differences page](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/versionmisc.shtml).

It's been a while, but I am pretty sure I got at least one Shiny Stone in Pokémon Moon when I had my Pokémon carry out the Brilliant Stone Hunting path to farm evolutionary stones.

Comment: Both stones arent version exclusives. I have multiple of both in my bag thanks to Pelago

Comment: I've finally found them.